# Floated elements jump when hiding another floated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have grid of floated elements, for which I created a filter. I want this filter to hide and show the items and while doing so I want the items to re adjust with transitions and fades.. At the moment the items just jump around.

As you can see here:

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5saxp0vh/)**

How can I make the items slide to their position?

Heres the code:

HTML

```
<ul class="filters">
    <li data="1">filter 1</li>
    <li data="2">filter 2</li>
    <li data="3">filter 3</li>
    <li data="4">filter 4</li>
</ul>
<br>
<ul class="items">
    <li data="1">1</li>
    <li data="2">2</li>
    <li data="1">3</li>
    <li data="3">4</li>
    <li data="4">5</li>
    <li data="2">6</li>
    <li data="3">7</li>
    <li data="4">8</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.filters li {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.items li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready( function() {


    $('.filters li').click( function () { 
        var data;

        data = $(this).attr('data');
        $('.items li').each( function() {
            if($(this).attr('data') !== data) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
            }
            else {
                $(this).fadeIn();
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: You would need a different operation than `fadeIn/Out` as that involves the `display` property and that cannot be animated or transitioned.

Comment: I could use opacity or visibility, but then the items would still take their space in DOM.

Comment: It's very complicated. Perhaps animate height/width instead.

Comment: ye, now that i think of it. It doesnt seem as easy as I initially thought

Comment: I've thrown a quick and dirty example as an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments you would need a different operation than `fadeIn/Out` as that involves the display property and that cannot be animated or transitioned.

Animating non-`display` values seems more optimal.

Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.filters li').click(function() {
    var data;

    data = $(this).attr('data');
    $('.items li').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('data') !== data) {
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('hidden');
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.filters li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.items li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
li.hidden {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="filters">
  <li data="1">filter 1</li>
  <li data="2">filter 2</li>
  <li data="3">filter 3</li>
  <li data="4">filter 4</li>
</ul>
<br>
<ul class="items">
  <li data="1">1</li>
  <li data="2">2</li>
  <li data="1">3</li>
  <li data="3">4</li>
  <li data="4">5</li>
  <li data="2">6</li>
  <li data="3">7</li>
  <li data="4">8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's a great solution!! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You could set a delay for the fade in to ensure the fade out has completed.

The 500ms delay below is is a slightly longer duration as the fade in.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.filters li').click(function() {
    var data;

    data = $(this).attr('data');
    $('.items li').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('data') !== data) {
        $(this).fadeOut();
      } else {
        $(this).delay(525).fadeIn();
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.filters li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.items li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="filters">
  <li data="1">filter 1</li>
  <li data="2">filter 2</li>
  <li data="3">filter 3</li>
  <li data="4">filter 4</li>
</ul>
<br>
<ul class="items">
  <li data="1">1</li>
  <li data="2">2</li>
  <li data="1">3</li>
  <li data="3">4</li>
  <li data="4">5</li>
  <li data="2">6</li>
  <li data="3">7</li>
  <li data="4">8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the overlap of fadeOut and fadeIn that makes it look like they are jumping.

Try hiding the filtered out items quick and slideDown the applicable boxes:

```
$(document).ready( function() {


$('.filters li').click( function () { 
    var data;

    data = $(this).attr('data');
    $('.items li').each( function() {
        if($(this).attr('data') !== data) {
            $(this).slideUp();
        }
        else {
            $(this).delay(525).slideDown();
        }
    });

});
```

});